# Spring WebClient without chunked encoding

Tags: reactor-netty, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

I need to use `Spring` reactive `WebClient` without default `chunked encoding` mode, which is "enforced" by underlying `HttpClient` and `Netty` based stack. Unfortunately the server I need to communicate with does not support this mode, even thou it supports rest of the HTTP 1.1 specs.

I know there is an option to set `Content-Length` header manually, but that requires you to operate with some `DataBuffer` like structure and I would like to use as much of the provided support (BodyInserters, Multipart support etc...). After some digging I found something similar is used at `HttpClientConfiguration` level for `GET` and `HEAD` requests, which are buffered in advance. I would like to implement something similar to this, but I am not sure at which level (if it is even possible) best to do so. Ideally I would like to implement some middleware which would only buffer incoming body data until upstream completes and then set `Content-Length` for downstream. I am not concerned about memory usage.

Comment: If anyone faces similar issue, I bypassed it by creating message body synchronously (still much faster than HTTP transfer, so no extra blocking is introduced) using RestTemplate HttpMessageConverters, therefore I don´t need additional custom logic for different body types and than using WebClient with Content-Length set. This way I can keep all additional logic implemented as ExchangeFilterFunction and don´t need extra threads if using some sync client.